# Can't change HDMI resolution 800x600 - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, display-resolution

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this problem. I restarted my computer and my second screen (HDMI) is now stuck in 800x600.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please describe in more detail what you have already tried and how it failed. It is likely that someone here can direct you to something you haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you have tried going to the 'Display' settings and tried changing it there? After that, you could try to going to 'Hardware' and maybe checking to see if it detecting the right monitor settings, you can change it from here as well. I would recommend last maybe to try installing/reinstalling the graphics driver..

Comment: I came home to it working fine. I have all the resolutions I normally have.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I reinstalled my Nvidia drivers I used the code "install --reinstall" but this time i purged them restarted and then installed them restarted and it worked. I still don't know why this happened because I didn’t change anything.